# How to update a value on _Layout from the model loaded in the content page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In the _Layout there is a Notifications menu item, which needs to show the number of new notifications for the active user. I have this info with the Model in the content page. How can I transfer this information to the _Layout page without using Ajax and without changing my model?

Thanks!

Comment: Just pass the `model` to your `_Layout`. Place it at the top..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao then how about  @RenderBody()?

Comment: If you cannot change the model, pass the information as a `ViewBag` property. But you would be better off having a base view model with the common property and define the base view model in the layout

Comment: @StephenMuecke could you please elaborate a bit on `But you would be better off having a base view model with the common property and define the base view model in the layout ` part?

Comment: Same `model` you can pass it to any `view` which is rendered using `RenderBody`. That's what @StephenMuecke mentioned it to define as a `base model`

Comment: @renakre, Are you using view models? If so (and you should be) then have a class (say) `VMBase` which contains your property. Then the view model that you use in the view inherits from that (as do all the other view models) and in the layout you have `@model VMBase` so that you can access the property but not make the layout dependant on a specific concrete view model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I am using view models. So, you mean I can use the `@model VMBase` in _Layout and in the content view at the same time, is that right?

Comment: Say you view model is `class ProductVM : VMBase { ... }` the in the layout `@model VMBase` and in the main view `@model ProductVM` Th layout has access to the base class properties and the main view has access to all properties.

Comment: The other alternative would be to generate the menu in the layout by using `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view of the menu, in which case you can have a specific menu view model and set what ever properties you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your view (content page) assign Active Users value like below

```
@{
ViewBag.ActiveUsers=Model.ActiveUsers;
}
```

And Use it in your _Layout as like below

```
@if (ViewBag.ActiveUsers!=null)
{
<span>@ViewBag.ActiveUsers</span>
}
```